# kotlin totalizar o sumar un campo de un arraylist llenado por una consulta query a (sqlserver)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

hola comunidad soy nuevo y estoy adentrándome en kotlin, necesito de su ayuda, estoy necesitando totalizar un campo de una consulta que realizo a sqlserver del cual extraigo nombre_vendedor y total_ventas,
los datos del detalle (vendedor,ventas)se presentan bien en un RecyclerView(1 rv_ventas), pero necesito realizar la suma del total de las ventas e insertarlas al final del detalle en otro Recyclerview(2 rv_total) o puede ser en un textview tambien.-
he intentado traer la suma total con una consulta query, pero al momento de presentar los datos de la suma se me termina repitiendo en los 2 RecyclerView que tengo creado, tanto en la que tengo para el detalle RecyclerView(rv_ventas) como en el que tengo para el total RecyclerView(rv_total).-

- otro forma seria procesar el campo ventas del arraylist que contiene el detalle de las ventas pero no se cuando procesarlas ni como procesarlas.-
  aqui parte de la consulta.-

///// databasehelper.kt

```
fun getVentas(rv: RecyclerView) {
        this.rv = rv
        query = "SELECT sucursal AS Sucursal, FORMAT(SUM(total), '###,###,###') as Total   \n" +
                "FROM  MODULO_VENTA_HIST\n" +
                "WHERE  (fecha2 = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) AND (estado <> 9)\n" +
                "GROUP BY sucursal"
        records = ArrayList<Venta>() as ArrayList<Any>
        adapter = VentasAdapter(records as ArrayList<Venta>)
        functionType = 3
        SyncData().execute("")
    }
fun getVentast(rv3: RecyclerView) {
        this.rv3 = rv3
        query = "SELECT FORMAT(SUM(total), '###,###,###') as Totalvt   \n" +
                "FROM     MODULO_VENTA_HIST\n" +
                "WHERE  (fecha2 = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())) AND (estado <> 9)"
        records = ArrayList<Ventat>() as ArrayList<Any>
        adapter = VentasAdaptert(records as ArrayList<Ventat>)
        functionType = 7
       SyncData().execute("")
    }
```

/////// mi adapters
// ventas adapter detalle

```
class VentasAdapter(val ventas: ArrayList<Venta>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<VentasAdapter.ViewHolder>()
{
    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val txtSucursal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSucursal) as TextView
        val txtTotal = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTotal) as TextView

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): VentasAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.lo_ventas, p0, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return ventas.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
        val venta: Venta = ventas[p1]
        p0.txtSucursal.text = venta.Sucursal.toString()
        p0.txtTotal.text = venta.Total

    }
}

// ventas adapter , presenta total extraido de consulta en rv_total
class VentasAdaptert(val ventast: ArrayList<Ventat>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<VentasAdaptert.ViewHolder>()
{
    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
       val txtTotaltv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTotaltv) as TextView
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): VentasAdaptert.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(p0.context).inflate(R.layout.lo_ventast, p0, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return ventast.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
        val ventat: Ventat = ventast[p1]
        p0.txtTotaltv.text = ventat.Totalvt

    }
}
```

/// mi ventas activity

```
class VentasActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    lateinit var rv: RecyclerView
    lateinit var rv3: RecyclerView

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ventas)

        //llamar detalle 
        rv = findViewById(R.id.rvVentas)
        rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
        MainActivity.db.ctx = this
        MainActivity.db.getVentas(rv)

        //llamar total ventas 
        rv3= findViewById(R.id.rvtc1)
        rv3.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
        MainActivity.db.ctx = this
        MainActivity.db.getVentast(rv3)
```